# how to show asset image inside box decoration

Tags: flutter

this is my code using network image inside box decoration.It works completely fine.

```
           Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: new NetworkImage(img),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                   )
                 )
            ),
            )
```

I want to change images from network to asset image so I can use images from assets folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `new NetworkImage(img)` to

```
Image.asset("path/to/image").image
```

or

```
AssetImage("path/to/image")
```

This will load an image from the assets instead of the internet.